# GCP Dataflow batch processing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am doing POC for GCP Dataflow batch processing.

I want to pass Pandas Dataframe as batch input and perform columnar transformation and return same batch again.

I refer example provided in below link for MultipyByTwo
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/

when I input Pandas Dataframe process_batch function is not executing.

Can you please let me know why and if possible please provide me example.

Code -
pd = read_excel(path)

result1 = ( pd | "test batch" >> beam.ParDo(TestBatch(argv)))

DoFn Class -

class (TestBatch(beam.DoFn):
def init(self, args: Any):
self.args = args
print("(TestBatch.init")

```
def setup(self) -> None:
    print("(TestBatch.setup")

def process_batch(self, batch: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    print("(TestBatch.process_batch")

    print(batch)

    yield batch
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at Beam Dataframes, e.g., https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.dataframe.io.html#apache_beam.dataframe.io.read_excel.This allows you to process the dataframes more efficiently.

For your case, this code example should work:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("beers.csv")


class ProcessDf(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, e: pd.DataFrame):
        print(e)
        return e


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    p | beam.Create([df]) | beam.ParDo(ProcessDf())
```

The Beam pipeline needs to start with a Pipeline.

https://beam.apache.org/get-started/ has more information. Tour of Beam is a great place to play with some basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks @XQ Hu, my requirement is to process data in batch. I want to use process_batch from apache beam with pd.DataFrame. Do I need to add my own BatchConverter for pd.DataFrame? I can see that "ListBatchConverter" and "NumpyBatchConverter" batch converters are available. Request you to please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: Both could be used if you want to process a batch of pd.DataFrame for sure. Unfortunately, I could not find a good documentation. Here is the some test code: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/typehints/batch_test.py#L58C11-L58C11